# BGL - determine all mincuts

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, graph

Given a graph, I want to find all edges (if any), that if removed spilt the graph into two components.

An initial idea would have been to assign a weight of 1 to all edges, then calculate the mincut of the graph. mincut > 1 implies there is no single edge that when removed causes a split.

For mincut == 1, it would have been nice if the algorithm would provide for each mincut the edges it consists of.

Unfortunately, BGL does not seem to support that kind of thing:

> The stoer_wagner_min_cut function determines exactly one of the min-cuts as well as its weight.

(http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/stoer_wagner_min_cut.html)

Is there a way to make this work (i.e. to determine more than one mincut) with the BGL or will I have to come up with something different?

Comment: So you want to find all cuts with exactly one edge in them? I would expect boost supports checks for connectedness, so you should be able to check for each edge whether the graph remains connected if you remove only that edge. Alternatively, [Tarjan's algorithm to find bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28graph_theory%29#Tarjan.27s_Bridge-finding_algorithm) would be faster; maybe check whether that's implemented in boost, or you can implement it yourself, it's description doesn't seem complicated.

Comment: Isn't checking connectivity for each edge a massive overhead? Thanks for tarjan. However, what if I later wanted to modify the algorithm to check - in the absence of bridges - for pairs (e0,e1) of edges whose deletions would split the graph? Can't very well run tarjan once per edge, can I?

Comment: You want [k-connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-edge-connected_graph#Computational_aspects) in that case, which is often solved using flow networks, but I'm not sure how to efficiently check for all sets of k edges deleting which would disconnect the graph. Maybe for [biconnectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component) there is something, but you'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

This may come a little bit late...

From what I see you only need to find all edges that don't belong to any cycle in the graph(assuming the graph is already connected).

This can be done by iteratively removing leaf nodes(and the edges connected to a them), much like what you do in [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn.27s_algorithm), until there's no leaf node left i.e. every edge in the remaining graph belongs to at least one cycle. All edges removed during the process will be the ones you want.

In pseudocode, for a connected undirected graph `G=(V,E)`, you can do this:

```
S = Ø
while(there exists a node n∈V s.t. degree(n)==1)
    e = edge connected to n
    S = S∪{e}
    E = E-{e}
    V = V-{n}
return S
```

which can be done in O(|V|+|E|) time